# Изменить input используя document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

Имеются несколько форм, в них элемент input. Ловлю их id вот так:

```
var form_id = $('input[name="btn_onoff"]').attr('id');
```

Пытаясь изменить value вот так

```
document.querySelector('#' + form_id).innerHTML = "Ожидание..";
```

ничего не выходит :(

Id уникальны.

В чём может быть причины сего явления?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина в том, что у инпута нет `innerHTML`.

```
document.querySelector('#' + form_id).value = "Ожидание..";
```

Answer (score 1):

У input нет атрибута innerHTML, нужно использовать value

```
document.querySelector('#' + form_id).value = "Ожидание.."
```